# PHP thank you only on successful submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms

So I have a form with both javascript validation to check each field is filed and a jquery ajax script to stop the page reloading.

The PHP script is very simple and only emails the fields of the form.
The problem is I need to ONLY show the thank you message if each field is filled out, and at the moment it appears to be showing it when I just enter the name field.
It doesn't show it if i just enter either the email or message field though and I can't work out why (I'm bad at PHP).

```
<?php 



$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Telephone Number: $telephone \n Priority: $priority \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@address.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

if(mail($name,$email,$message,$headers)){
    echo "<p>Thanks for your mail...</p>";
}


?>
```

Javascript that stops page reloading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".contactus").submit(function() {

                $.post("mail.php", $(".contactus").serialize(),

                    function(data) {
                        $("#formResponse").html(data);
                    }
                );
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Form validation.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">


var FormName = "contactus";



var RequiredFields = "name,email,priority,message";



function ValidateRequiredFields()
{
var FieldList = RequiredFields.split(",")
var BadList = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < FieldList.length; i++) {
    var s = eval('document.' + FormName + '.' + FieldList[i] + '.value');
    s = StripSpacesFromEnds(s);
    if(s.length < 1) { BadList.push(FieldList[i]); }
    }
if(BadList.length < 1) { return true; }
var ess = new String();
if(BadList.length > 1) { ess = 's'; }
var message = new String('\n\nThe following field' + ess + ' are required:\n');
for(var i = 0; i < BadList.length; i++) { message += '\n' + BadList[i]; }
alert(message);
return false;
}

function StripSpacesFromEnds(s)
{
while((s.indexOf(' ',0) == 0) && (s.length> 1)) {
    s = s.substring(1,s.length);
    }
while((s.lastIndexOf(' ') == (s.length - 1)) && (s.length> 1)) {
    s = s.substring(0,(s.length - 1));
    }
if((s.indexOf(' ',0) == 0) && (s.length == 1)) { s = ''; }
return s;
}
// -->
</script>
```

And the form

```
<form action="mail.php" id="myform" class="contactus" onsubmit="return ValidateRequiredFields(); this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;"   name="contactus" method="POST">
<p class="floatleft" style="width:200px; background-color:#FF0000; height:50px; line-height:50px; margin:0; padding:0;">Nameeeeee</p> <input class="sizetext" type="text" maxlength="10" name="name">
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<p class="floatleft" style="width:200px;">Email</p> <input class="sizetext" type="text" maxlength="10" name="email">
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<p class="floatleft" style="width:200px;">Telephone</p> <input class="sizetext" type="text" maxlength="10" name="telephone">


<p>Priority</p>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>

</select>
<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />

<br />
<input class="buttonstyle" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: eval abuse and Unnecessary use of constructors (`new String`) spotted.

Comment: why don't you check to see if those fields are filled out in the javascript, and only make the post to the php that sends mail if all the fields are filled out?

Comment: I suppose what I'm really asking is how to do PHP form validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];

$check = array('name', 'email', 'priority', 'message', 'telephone');
$send = true;

foreach($check as $key => $value){
    if(empty($_POST[$value])){
        $send = false;
    }
}


$formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Telephone Number: $telephone \n Priority: $priority \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "myemail@address.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

if($send && mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
    echo "<p>Thanks for your mail...</p>";
}
else{
    die('Error!');
}
```

Comment: This still tells me 'thanks for your mail' when just filling in the name field and nothing else.

Comment: Nope, this just sends regardless of what fields are checked

Comment: try `if(!empty($_POST['value'])` instead of isset

Comment: my fault, take out the "!", it should be `if( empty($_POST[$value]))`

Comment: Now it just throws up an error no matter what fields are filled out and doesnt send the email

Comment: Ok thank you, it works now! And shows the appropriate message depending on failure or validation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most easier way would be to check if your POST fields are present and not empty. Probably there is a more elegant solution if you want to check every field individually, but here goes:

```
 if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
    if(mail($name,$email,$message,$headers)){
echo "<p>Thanks for your mail...</p>";
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code around

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Telephone Number: $telephone \n Priority: $priority \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "myemail@address.co.uk";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    $mail = @mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);

    if($mail){
        echo "<p>Thanks for your mail...</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error Sending Mail " ;
    }

}
```